# Show a bitmap centered along with the AlertDialog button in a full screen dialog

Tags: android, bitmap, android-alertdialog

I want to show the mentioned things center in the dialog, for example, now one of them is showing like this:

[image]

And it should show like this:

[image]

I mean, the same space above the bitmap and under the button.

The same should apply to the width of the bitmap, the same space should be left to the left and to the right, my current code seems to achieve that.

This is how I call the dialog:

```
 private fun showFullScreenDialog()
    {
        val vacationDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(fragment.context,R.style.DialogTheme)
        val factory = LayoutInflater.from(fragment.context);
        var view = factory.inflate(R.layout.sample, null)
        view.dialog_imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        vacationDialog.setView(view)
        vacationDialog.setPositiveButton("Cerrar"){dialog, which ->
            dialog.dismiss()

        }
        vacationDialog.show()

    }
```

This is sample.xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:background="@color/white"
>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this the defined DialogTheme style:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    </style>
```

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: In your style _android:layout_height_ make it _wrap_content_ and set gravity to _center_

Comment: I tried both your solution and the one from @Shivam Oberoi, even combining them, but to no avail, anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

use relative layout instead of linear layout-:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:background="@color/white"
>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If none of other solutions work, try to delete the xml layout and create a new one. The android studio sometimes gets buggy. 
I use Constraint Layout to centre anything:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".YourActivity">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in your case the layout doesn't even inflate, it throws an error in var view = factory.inflate(R.layout.sample, null), I updated to the last version on   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout: to see if I got lucky, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, I did as you said.